# Why the NIntegrate can not be worked out?

Tags: numerical-integration

The integrand includes k, Sin[2*theta], and T. k is constant, theta is one of the variables (the other variables are x, y and fi),  and T is functions of x, y, theta and fi. I found that it needs more than 2600s to work out the integration G = NIntegrate[k^2 * Sin[2 * theta] * T, {x, x0 - 5 * 10^(-10),
x0 + 5 * 10^(-10)}, {y, y0 - 5 * 10^(-10), y0 + 5 * 10^(-10)}, {theta,
0, Pi/2}, {fi, 0, 2*Pi}] (x0 and y0 have been given)? How to improve the speed of the calculation? Many thanks!

The codes are as following:

```
Clear["`*"]
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
mu = 5;
HBAR = 1.05457266*10^(-34);
ME = 9.1093897*10^(-31);
ELEC = 1.60217733*10^(-19);
kc = Sqrt[2*ME*ELEC/HBAR^2];
k = kc*Sqrt[mu];
afa = Pi/90;
d = 0.335*10^(-9);
v1 = kc^2*3;
v2 = kc^2*2;
v3 = kc^2*1;
K = 2.95*10^(10);

Kh[0] = {0, 0, 0};
Ks[0] = {0, 0, 0};
Kh[1] = {K, 0, 0};
Ks[1] = {K*Cos[afa], K*Sin[afa], 0};
Kh[2] = {K/2, K*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[2] = {K*Cos[afa + Pi/3], K*Sin[afa + Pi/3], 0};
Kh[3] = {-K/2, K*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[3] = {K*Cos[afa + 2*Pi/3], K*Sin[afa + 2*Pi/3], 0};
Kh[4] = {-K, 0, 0};
Ks[4] = {K*Cos[afa + Pi], K*Sin[afa + Pi], 0};
Kh[5] = {-K/2, -K*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[5] = {K*Cos[afa + 4*Pi/3], K*Sin[afa + 4*Pi/3], 0};
Kh[6] = {K/2, -K*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[6] = {K*Cos[afa + 5*Pi/3], K*Sin[afa + 5*Pi/3], 0};
integrand[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, theta_?NumericQ, fi_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{ks, r, p, M1, M2, S1, S2, S, T, S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, 
    S16, S17, S21, S22, S23, S24, S25, S26, S27, S31, S32, S33, S34, 
    S35, S36, S37, S41, S42, S43, S44, S45, S46, S47, S51, S52, S53, 
    S54, S55, S56, S57, S61, S62, S63, S64, S65, S66, S67, S71, S72, 
    S73, S74, S75, S76, S77},
   ks = {k*Sin[theta]*Cos[fi], k*Sin[theta]*Sin[fi], k*Cos[theta]};
   p[i_] := k^2 - Total[(ks + Kh[i])^2];
   r = {x, y, 0};
   M1 = {{0, v1, v1, v1, v1, v1, v1}, {v1, p[1], v1, v2, v3, v2, 
      v1}, {v1, v1, p[2], v1, v2, v3, v2}, {v1, v2, v1, p[3], v1, v2, 
      v3}, {v1, v3, v2, v1, p[4], v1, v2}, {v1, v2, v3, v2, v1, p[5], 
      v1}, {v1, v1, v2, v3, v2, v1, p[6]}};
   M2 := {{0, v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[1] - Kh[0] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[2] - Kh[0] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[3] - Kh[0] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[4] - Kh[0] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[5] - Kh[0] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[6] - Kh[0] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[0] - Kh[1] + Kh[0])*r]], p[1], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[2] - Kh[1] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[3] - Kh[1] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[4] - Kh[1] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[5] - Kh[1] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[6] - Kh[1] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[0] - Kh[2] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[1] - Kh[2] + Kh[1])*r]], p[2], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[3] - Kh[2] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[4] - Kh[2] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[5] - Kh[2] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[6] - Kh[2] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[0] - Kh[3] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[1] - Kh[3] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[2] - Kh[3] + Kh[2])*r]], p[3], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[4] - Kh[3] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[5] - Kh[3] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[6] - Kh[3] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[0] - Kh[4] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[1] - Kh[4] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[2] - Kh[4] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[3] - Kh[4] + Kh[3])*r]], p[4], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[5] - Kh[4] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[6] - Kh[4] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[0] - Kh[5] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[1] - Kh[5] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[2] - Kh[5] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[3] - Kh[5] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[4] - Kh[5] + Kh[4])*r]], p[5], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[6] - Kh[5] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[0] - Kh[6] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[1] - Kh[6] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[2] - Kh[6] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[3] - Kh[6] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[4] - Kh[6] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[5] - Kh[6] + Kh[5])*r]], p[6]}};
   S1 := Transpose[Eigenvectors[M1]] . 
     DiagonalMatrix[
      Exp[I*d*(Sqrt[(k*Cos[theta])^2 + Eigenvalues[M1]] - 
          k*Cos[theta])]] . Inverse[Transpose[Eigenvectors[M1]]];
   S2 := Transpose[Eigenvectors[M2]] . 
     DiagonalMatrix[
      Exp[I*d*(Sqrt[(k*Cos[theta])^2 + Eigenvalues[M2]] - 
          k*Cos[theta])]] . Inverse[Transpose[Eigenvectors[M2]]];
   S := S2 . S1;
   {{S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17}, {S21, S22, S23, S24, S25, 
      S26, S27}, {S31, S32, S33, S34, S35, S36, S37}, {S41, S42, S43, 
      S44, S45, S46, S47}, {S51, S52, S53, S54, S55, S56, S57}, {S61, 
      S62, S63, S64, S65, S66, S67}, {S71, S72, S73, S74, S75, S76, 
      S77}} = S;
   T = S11*Conjugate[S11] + S21*Conjugate[S21] + S31*Conjugate[S31] + 
     S41*Conjugate[S41] + S51*Conjugate[S51] + S61*Conjugate[S61] + 
     S71*Conjugate[
       S71] + (Conjugate[S11]*S21*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[1] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[2] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[2] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S51]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[4])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S51]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[4])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S61]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[5])*r]]) + 
     Conjugate[
      Conjugate[S11]*S21*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[1] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[2] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[2] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S51]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[4])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S51]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[4])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S61]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[5])*r]]];
   k^2*Sin[2*theta]*T];
G := NIntegrate[
   integrand[x, y, theta, fi], {x, x0 - 5*10^(-10), 
    x0 + 5*10^(-10)}, {y, y0 - 5*10^(-10), y0 + 5*10^(-10)}, {theta, 
    0, Pi/2}, {fi, 0, 2*Pi}];
G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Clear["`*"]
x=1*10^(-9);
y=0.5*10^(-9);
mu=5;
HBAR=1.05457266*10^(-34);
ME=9.1093897*10^(-31);
ELEC=1.60217733*10^(-19);
kc=Sqrt[2*ME*ELEC/HBAR^2];
k=kc*Sqrt[mu];
afa=Pi/90;
d=0.335*10^(-9);
v1=kc^2*3;
v2=kc^2*2;
v3=kc^2*1;
K=2.95*10^(10);
r={x,y,0};
Kh[0]={0,0,0};
Ks[0]={0,0,0};
Kh[1]={K,0,0};
Ks[1]={K*Cos[afa],K*Sin[afa],0};
Kh[2]={K/2,K*Sqrt[3]/2,0};
Ks[2]={K*Cos[afa+Pi/3],K*Sin[afa+Pi/3],0};
Kh[3]={-K/2,K*Sqrt[3]/2,0};
Ks[3]={K*Cos[afa+2*Pi/3],K*Sin[afa+2*Pi/3],0};
Kh[4]={-K,0,0};
Ks[4]={K*Cos[afa+Pi],K*Sin[afa+Pi],0};
Kh[5]={-K/2,-K*Sqrt[3]/2,0};
Ks[5]={K*Cos[afa+4*Pi/3],K*Sin[afa+4*Pi/3],0};
Kh[6]={K/2,-K*Sqrt[3]/2,0};
Ks[6]={K*Cos[afa+5*Pi/3],K*Sin[afa+5*Pi/3],0};
```

Everything else should be define in a function that only applies when it has numeric arguments. Below, I don't go through all the typing to include all terms of T. BTW, it's much faster to assign all the parts of S to individual symbols. The function integrand could be made much faster using Compile, but I don't have time for that right now.

```
integrand[theta_?NumericQ,fi_?NumericQ]:=Module[{ks,p,M1,M2,S1,S2,S,T,S11,S12,S13,S14,S15,S16,S17,S21,S22,S23,S24,S25,S26,S27,S31,S32,S33,S34,S35,S36,S37,S41,S42,S43,S44,S45,S46,S47,S51,S52,S53,S54,S55,S56,S57,S61,S62,S63,S64,S65,S66,S67,S71,S72,S73,S74,S75,S76,S77},
ks={k*Sin[theta]*Cos[fi],k*Sin[theta]*Sin[fi],k*Cos[theta]};
p[i_]:=k^2-Total[(ks+Kh[i])^2];
M1={{0,v1,v1,v1,v1,v1,v1},{v1,p[1],v1,v2,v3,v2,v1},
  {v1,v1,p[2],v1,v2,v3,v2},{v1,v2,v1,p[3],v1,v2,v3},
  {v1,v3,v2,v1,p[4],v1,v2},{v1,v2,v3,v2,v1,p[5],v1},
  {v1,v1,v2,v3,v2,v1,p[6]}
};
M2 := {{0, v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[1] - Kh[0] + Kh[1])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[2] - Kh[0] + Kh[2])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[3] - Kh[0] + Kh[3])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[4] - Kh[0] + Kh[4])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[5] - Kh[0] + Kh[5])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[6] - Kh[0] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
 Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[0] - Kh[1] + Kh[0])*r]], p[1], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[2] - Kh[1] + Kh[2])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[3] - Kh[1] + Kh[3])*r]], 
v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[4] - Kh[1] + Kh[4])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[5] - Kh[1] + Kh[5])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[6] - Kh[1] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
 Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[0] - Kh[2] + Kh[0])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[1] - Kh[2] + Kh[1])*r]], p[2], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[3] - Kh[2] + Kh[3])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[4] - Kh[2] + Kh[4])*r]], 
v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[5] - Kh[2] + Kh[5])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[6] - Kh[2] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
 Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[0] - Kh[3] + Kh[0])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[1] - Kh[3] + Kh[1])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[2] - Kh[3] + Kh[2])*r]], p[3], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[4] - Kh[3] + Kh[4])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[5] - Kh[3] + Kh[5])*r]], 
v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[6] - Kh[3] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
 Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[0] - Kh[4] + Kh[0])*r]], 
v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[1] - Kh[4] + Kh[1])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[2] - Kh[4] + Kh[2])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[3] - Kh[4] + Kh[3])*r]], p[4], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[5] - Kh[4] + Kh[5])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[6] - Kh[4] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
 Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[0] - Kh[5] + Kh[0])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[1] - Kh[5] + Kh[1])*r]], 
v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[2] - Kh[5] + Kh[2])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[3] - Kh[5] + Kh[3])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[4] - Kh[5] + Kh[4])*r]], p[5], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[6] - Kh[5] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
 Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[0] - Kh[6] + Kh[0])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[1] - Kh[6] + Kh[1])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[2] - Kh[6] + Kh[2])*r]], 
v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[3] - Kh[6] + Kh[3])*r]], 
v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[4] - Kh[6] + Kh[4])*r]], 
v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[5] - Kh[6] + Kh[5])*r]], p[6]}};
S1 := Transpose[Eigenvectors[M1]].DiagonalMatrix[
Exp[I*d*(Sqrt[(k*Cos[theta])^2 + Eigenvalues[M1]] - 
    k*Cos[theta])]].Inverse[Transpose[Eigenvectors[M1]]];
S2 := Transpose[Eigenvectors[M2]].DiagonalMatrix[
Exp[I*d*(Sqrt[(k*Cos[theta])^2 + Eigenvalues[M2]] - 
    k*Cos[theta])]].Inverse[Transpose[Eigenvectors[M2]]];
S := S1.S2;
{{S11,S12,S13,S14,S15,S16,S17},
 {S21,S22,S23,S24,S25,S26,S27},
 {S31,S32,S33,S34,S35,S36,S37},
 {S41,S42,S43,S44,S45,S46,S47},
 {S51,S52,S53,S54,S55,S56,S57},
 {S61,S62,S63,S64,S65,S66,S67},
 {S71,S72,S73,S74,S75,S76,S77}}=S;
T=S11*Conjugate[S11]+S21*Conjugate[S21]+
  S31*Conjugate[S31]+S41*Conjugate[S41]+
  S51*Conjugate[S51]+S61*Conjugate[S61]+S71*Conjugate[S71]+
  (Conjugate[S11]*S21*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[1]-Kh[0])*r]]+
    Conjugate[S11]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[2]-Kh[0])*r]]+
    Conjugate[S11]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3]-Kh[0])*r]]
  );
  Re[k^2*Sin[2*theta]*T]
]
```

Then do the integral like this:

```
NIntegrate[integrand[theta,fi],{theta,0,Pi/2},{fi,0,2*Pi}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer. It is very useful for me.

Comment: Dear Ersek, I have another problem. Now, tmr is defined as tmr:={x,y,G}. When I export [Table[tmr, {x, -1*10^(-8), 1*10^(-8), 1.0*10^(-9)}, {y, -1*10^(-8), 1*10^(-8), 1.0*10^(-9)}] (i.e., 400 calculating points), I found the memory of the computer is always increasing and will result in "no more memory available" at last. However, if I reduce the the number of the calculating points, such as [Table[tmr, {x, -1*10^(-8), 1*10^(-8), 1.0*10^(-8)}, {y, -1*10^(-8), 1*10^(-8), 1.0*10^(-8)}] ((i.e., 9 calculating points)), the codes can give a correct result. How to solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: @user59546, Start a new question on this site for that problem.

Comment: I have re-edited the problem, and compared to the previous codes, now x and y are varibles of the integration (i.e., the integration become quadruple integral). However, I found that it needs more than 2600s to work out the integration. How to improve the speed of the calculation? Many thanks!